# How to upload file to google storage in multiple chunks?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, chunks, pre-signed-url

I am trying to upload file to google storage in multiple chunks but signed URL.

Below are the steps I am following:

1. Create Resumable Upload URL using Node.js.

Sample URL: `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/MYBUCKET/o?name=sdk2.txt&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2UrmFY9CKwkHFxsYdT71LcWa0zUVjG6iYfr9mHiwsIaG3c1goFiVURUPz6KFTIhtywndse00XaOkH7ftXPf82S7bNVRhPg`

2. Initiate a resumable upload session:

`POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/MYBUCKET/o?name=sdk2.txt&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2UrmFY9CKwkHFxsYdT71LcWa`

With these headers:

```
Content-Type:text/plain
name:sdk2.txt
Content-Length:0
x-goog-resumable:start
```

HTTPS response: `200 OK`

3. Send first chunk:

`PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/MYBUCKET/o?name=sdk2.txt&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2UrmFY9CKwkHFxsYdT71LcWa0zUVjG6iYfr9mHiwsIaG3c1goFiVURUPz6KFTIhtywndse00XaOkH7ftXPf82S7bNVRhPg`

With these headers:

```
Content-Type:text/plain
name:sdk2.txt
Content-Length: 262144
Content-Range: bytes 0-262143/331886
```

HTTPS response: `200 OK` with data:

```
 {
  "kind": "storage#object",
  "id": "MYBUCKET/sdk2.txt/1490608714382301",
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/testupload-sdk/o/sdk2.txt",
  "name": "sdk2.txt",
  "bucket": "MYBUCKET",
  "generation": "1490608714382301",
  "metageneration": "1",
  "timeCreated": "2017-03-27T09:58:34.164Z",
  "updated": "2017-03-27T09:58:34.164Z",
  "storageClass": "MULTI_REGIONAL",
  "timeStorageClassUpdated": "2017-03-27T09:58:34.164Z",
  "size": "0",
  "md5Hash": "1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==",
  "mediaLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/MYBUCKET/o/sdk2.txt?generation=1490608714382301&alt=media",
  "crc32c": "AAAAAA==",
  "etag": "CN33rZe29tICEAE="
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload#resume-upload) the above response should be `308` and not `200 OK`.

What am I doing wrong with these API calls?

Comment: I fixed formatting to make the question readable, but you may want to add some code.

Comment: did you find any information about this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Step 2 is not necessary. If you replace Step 2 with Step 3, then the response will return `308` as expected instead of `200`.

`x-goog-resumable` is only for the `XML API`, so you should omit it when using the `JSON API`.

In Step 1, the resumable upload was initialized. GCS generates the upload ID when the upload is initialized, so it's impossible to have an upload ID before initializing the upload.

Step 2 finalized the resumable upload with a 0-byte object since GCS interpreted it as the data to upload (due to Step 1 initializing the upload). As a result, Step 3 returned the response from Step 2. GCS will return the response from the request that created the object if the resumable upload was finalized.